# Can a monk make Martial Arts attacks while grappling and wielding a weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, monk, grapple

I'm planning on playing a grapple-oriented monk in my group's next 5e campaign, and was wondering about Martial Arts unarmed attacks while grappling.

Can a monk grapple a single target, attack them with a one-handed weapon, and then make an unarmed strike off of that attack?

I'm pretty sure I can do so if my non-grappling hand isn't holding a weapon, but I think the rules suggest that I can't do this if my non-grappling hand is holding a weapon.

Comment: Related: [What are the restrictions of an unarmed strike?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47537/what-are-the-restrictions-of-an-unarmed-strike), [Can you attack while you have two targets grappled?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/135198/can-you-attack-while-you-have-two-targets-grappled)

Comment: Are you specifically asking whether "grappling and wielding a weapon" counts as being "unarmed or wielding only monk weapons"? (Also, Flurry of Blows doesn't have the restrictions that the Martial Arts feature does, so you might want to edit that part out of the question.)

Comment: I think that answers my question. I was basically asking if unarmed strike is possible if you don't have a free hand not using a weapon while grappling. My concern was that an unarmed strike would be impossible without a free hand not holding a weapon, but it sounds like I was misinterpreting what an unarmed attack entails. Reading over the link you gave, it seems like it should work.  Am I correct in this interpretation?

Will edit the bit you mentioned.

Comment: Glad to help! Since you said the (first?) link answers your question, I've marked the question as a duplicate for now. If you have other questions, feel free to ask them as well, but search to see if it's been answered already first. Welcome to RPG.SE, and take the [tour] if you haven't already!